# How can I create a list with previous ordered products in Shopify?

Tags: php, html, css, shopify

Is there any way to create a list of previously ordered items, with images as well, in Shopify?
Basically what I'm after is a list on the front page of 3 items that were previously purchased by the user.

Comment: I literally have no idea what to try

Comment: What is the solution you are trying to solve? Where are you planning on using this information for, etc.  Your question really doesn't provide that much detail into what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Does this need to be user specific? Will these users have been previously logged in (via user accounts) or do you just want to do something like show off popular items?

Comment: That's the catch, it should be user specific. If you aren't logged in, you won't see anything.

Comment: Look into the javascript API to see if you can get access to a user account token or id.  If you can do that, have a JSONP endpoint or something that provides products that the user bought (or put in their previously abandoned cart) and display them.  You can write your own API that would provide details, links to the product and links to the image based on various parts of the Shopify API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user will need to be logged in for the following to work. If the user is logged in, then you can use the following code to display their orders. This will display only 3 orders.

```
{% if customer.orders.size != 0 %}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="order_number">Order</th>
      <th class="date">Date</th>
      <th class="payment_status">Payment Status</th>
      <th class="fulfillment_status">Fulfillment Status</th>
      <th class="total">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for order in customer.orders limit:3 %}
    <tr class="{% cycle 'odd', 'even' %} {% if order.cancelled %}cancelled_order{% endif %}">
      <td>{{ order.name | link_to: order.customer_url }}</td>
      <td><span class="note">{{ order.created_at | date: "%b %d, %Y" }}</span></td>
      <td><span class="status_{{ order.financial_status }}">{{ order.financial_status }}</span></td>
      <td><span class="status_{{ order.fulfillment_status }}">{{ order.fulfillment_status }}</span></td>
      <td><span class="total money">{{ order.total_price | money }}</span></td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
{% else %}
    <p>You haven't placed any orders yet.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a customer is logged in, there will be a `customer` liquid variable available with lots of data about the user. If you look through the [docs](http://wiki.shopify.com/Customer_variable#customer.orders), there is a member variable called `order` which will give you an array of all of the users orders. There is also a variable called `recent_order` which will give you the most recent order by the user.

If you are familiar with the Liquid template language used by Shopify, this should be enough to get you started. Generally, the [Shopify wiki](http://wiki.shopify.com/Main_Page) is very helpful.